# Dataframe merge on multiple conditions in date range

Tags: python, pandas, merge, left-join

I have two dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'orderID': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'Sales': [100, 110, 120, 140, 150], 'Name': ['John', "Maria", "Maria", "John", "Cesar"],
                   'Date':['2022-01-08', '2022-02-10', '2022-02-15', '2022-02-05', '2022-05-07']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Negotiation': [100, 110, 121, 134, 141], 'Sales': [100, 110, 120, 140, 150], 'Name': ['John', "Maria", "Maria", "John", "Ricardo"],
                   'Date':['2022-01-01', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-30', '2022-02-01', '2022-09-01']})
```

I need to merge them based on 'Name' and date, but the dates aren't the same, so they need to be a date range yielding a dataframe as follow:

```
df_m = pd.DataFrame({'orderID': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'Sales': [100, 110, 120, 140, 150], 'Name_x': ['John', "Maria", "Maria", "John", "Cesar"],
                   'Date_X':['2022-01-08', '2022-02-10', '2022-02-15', '2022-02-05', '2022-05-07'], 'Negotiation': [100, 110, 121, 134, 141], 'Sales': [100, 110, 120, 140, 150], 'Name_y': ['John', "Maria", "Maria", 'John',  "Null"], 'Date_y':['2022-01-01', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-30', '2022-02-01', 'Null']})
```

I need to avoid merging with the wrong dates as follow:

```
df_m_wrong_date = pd.DataFrame({'orderID': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'Sales': [100, 110, 120, 140, 150], 'Name_x': ['John', "Maria", "Maria", "John", "Cesar"],
                   'Date_X':['2022-01-08', '2022-02-10', '2022-02-15', '2022-02-05', '2022-05-07'], 'Negotiation': [100, 110, 121, 134, 141], 'Sales': [100, 110, 120, 140, 150], 'Name_y': ['John', "Maria", "Maria", 'John',  "Null"], 'Date_y':['2022-02-01', '2022-01-30', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-01', 'Null']})
```

Comment: dat = [df,df2]
df = pd.concat(dat)
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset = (['Name', 'Date']))) is it what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge_asof`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

out = (pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('Date'), 
                    df2.sort_values('Date').rename(columns={'Date': 'NegDate'}),
                    by=['Sales', 'Name'],
                    left_on='Date', right_on='NegDate', direction='backward')
         .sort_values('orderID'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   orderID  Sales   Name       Date  Negotiation    NegDate
0       10    100   John 2022-01-08        100.0 2022-01-01
2       11    110  Maria 2022-02-10        110.0 2022-01-20
3       12    120  Maria 2022-02-15        121.0 2022-01-30
1       13    140   John 2022-02-05        134.0 2022-02-01
4       14    150  Cesar 2022-05-07          NaN        NaT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate it like that. It drops if name and date is same. I think it is unlogical to merging it. If you want to drop wrong dates you can do it with `pd.to_datetime`

```
data = [df,df2]
df = pd.concat(data)
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset = (['Name', 'Date'])))
```